# Multiple HTML pages with different display time in same iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have five `HTML` pages and an iFrame.

I need to display the `HTML` pages in an iFrame with specific display time for each page. The delay should include the time for loading the iFrame container. Say first page has a display time of 10 seconds, second page a display time of 20 seconds, third page a display time of 30 seconds and so on.

How do I display all these pages bound to their display time?

I have tried many ways to add the load time my including iframe.load in the code but it causes some weird recursions which alters the display time.

Comment: You really need to include your code ..

Comment: What is the closest attempt you have done? Can you show us? We can't help you to understand what your issue is. Also better provide a fiddle because it's unclear what do you mean with "it causes some wiered recursions which alters the display time "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest loading the first source only after the iframe.load for the page initialization is finished. Code uses jQuery.

The logs are of course for making sure that the timing is exactly as you want it to be, with only minimal offsets (one-digit milliseconds when I tested it.)

```
<iframe id="myiframe"></iframe>

<script>
var currentFrameId = 0;
    var frameLengths = [0,10000,20000,30000,40000];//The first page should be displayed as soon as ready
    var frameURLs = ["http://example.com/page1", "http://example.com/page2", "http://example.com/page3", "http://example.com/page4", "http://example.com/page5"];

    function nextFrame(){
        if(currentFrameId == frameURLs.length)
            return;
        console.log((new Date().getTime()) + ": setting iframe src to " + frameURLs[currentFrameId] + "(frame id " + currentFrameId + ")");
        $('#myiframe').attr('src',frameURLs[currentFrameId]);
        currentFrameId++;
    }

    $(function(){
        console.log((new Date().getTime()) + ": starting javascript");

        $('#myiframe').load(function(){
            console.log((new Date().getTime()) + ": iframe loaded for frame id " + currentFrameId);
            window.setTimeout(nextFrame, frameLengths[currentFrameId]); 
        });

        nextFrame();
    });
</script>
```

See the working example under https://jsfiddle.net/kx2vdj16/